# Add native watchkit extension to existing xamarin app

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, watchkit

Is it possible to create **native** apple watch extension for **current Xamarin** app? The thing is - I have developed an app with Xamarin platforms. But now i want to extend it with Apple Watch extension. Am I to re-develop the app from scratch or there is another way like adding **native** WatchKit extension?

Thanks

Comment: See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/watch/

Comment: I might have written not clearly but what i really want to achieve is to create **native swift** extension for existing **xamarin** app

Comment: @SergeyPetrachkov Currently there is no *direct* way to create a ObjC/Swift `-based .appex` independendly of a ObjC/Swift app project (i.e. using a Xamarin-based host/container app). *Technically* it is possible by mod'ing the build process but you could not debug the `.appex` via the Xamarin container.

Comment: @SushiHangover, thanks